# How to make the overlap area of navigationBarTitle and navigationBarItem tappable - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

Currently only the middle part of the red area is tappable, and I know the below area is overlapping with navigationBarTitle, but I still wonder if it is feasible to make the below area to be tappable as well.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var taskStore: TaskStore
    @State var modalIsPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(taskStore.tasks) { index in
                    RowView(task: self.$taskStore.tasks[index])
                }
                .onMove { sourceIndices, destinationIndex in
                    self.taskStore.tasks.move(
                        fromOffsets: sourceIndices,
                        toOffset: destinationIndex
                    )
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    self.taskStore.tasks.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Tasks")
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: EditButton(),
                trailing:
                Button(
                    action: { self.modalIsPresented = true }
                ) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 50, leading: 50, bottom: 50, trailing: 10))
                    .background(Color.red)
                }
            )
            }
        .sheet(isPresented: $modalIsPresented) {
            NewTaskView(taskStore: self.taskStore)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView( taskStore: TaskStore() )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two minor change in your code

```
.navigationBarItems(
            leading: EditButton(),
            trailing:
            Button(
                action: { self.modalIsPresented = true }
            ) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
            }
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer man. While what I mean is to make that area which has stretched into barTitle's scope. I just added the photo of the area, but looks like it's not feasible.